# Node Js - Big Array usage

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, memory

I'm trying to make a matrix "box" full of "dots" using this:

```
let matrix = []
let size = 700


for (iz = 0; iz <= size; iz++) {
  iy = 0
  for (iy = 0; iy <= size; iy++) {
    ix = 0
    for (ix = 0; ix <= size; ix++) {
      matrix.push({
        x: ix,
        y: iy,
        z: iz
      })
      //if (ix === 10 && iy === 10 && iz === 10)
    }
  }
}
```

But it is using more RAM memory then I have.
I know that it will give a big data matrix, but, Is there another way to do that without using a lot of memory?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I guess the real question is, why do you need this matrix? Probably you are using it to solve another problem, and that original problem can be solved without it, so maybe if you can tell us why you are doing this it can help.